# React native fetch api ,Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id:0):cant find variable resarray1

Tags: react-native

I am trying to call an API using fetch and I get this error message in the yellow box on my phone:

> Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id:0): cant find variable resarray1

This is `AttendanceDetails` class:

```
'use strict'
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
AppRegistry,
StyleSheet,
Navigator,
Text,
View
} from 'react-native';
import api from './utilities/api';

export default class AttendanceDetails extends Component {

constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={

        resarray1:[],
        resarray2:[],
        total:'',
        present:'',
        absent:'',
        off:'',
        unmarked:'',
        totalHours:'',
        averageHours:'',
        greater12Hours:'',
        less8hours:''
    }
}

componentWillMount(){

    api.getAttendanceDetails().then((res)=>{
        this.setState({

            resarray1: res.data.attendance_details,
            resarray2: res.data.attendance_summary,
            total:resarray1[0].value,
            present:resarray1[1].value,
            absent:resarray1[2].value,
            off:resarray1[3].value,
            unmarked:resarray1[4].value,
            totalHours:resarray2[0].value,
            averageHours:resarray2[1].value,
            greater12Hours:resarray2[2].value,
            less8hours:resarray2[3].value

        })
    }); 
}

render() {
// console.log('details: ',this.state.resarray1,this.state.resarray2,this.state.less8hours)
return (
  <View style={styles.container}>

  <View>
  <Text>
  Attendance Summary
  </Text>
  </View>

  <View style={styles.containerRow}>

   <Text style={styles.welcome}>
    {this.state.total}
  </Text>

  </View>

  <View style={styles.containerRow}>

   <Text style={styles.welcome}>
    {this.state.present}
  </Text>

  </View>

  <View style={styles.containerRow}>

   <Text style={styles.welcome}>
    {this.state.absent}
  </Text>

  </View>

  <View style={styles.containerRow}>

   <Text style={styles.welcome}>
    {this.state.off}
  </Text>

  </View>

  <View style={styles.containerRow}>

   <Text style={styles.welcome}>
    {this.state.unmarked}
  </Text>

  </View>


  <View>
  <Text>
  Hourly Summary
  </Text>
  </View>

  <View style={styles.containerRow}>

   <Text style={styles.welcome}>
    {this.state.totalHours}
  </Text>

  </View>

  <View style={styles.containerRow}>

   <Text style={styles.welcome}>
    {this.state.averageHours}
  </Text>

  </View>

  <View style={styles.containerRow}>

   <Text style={styles.welcome}>
    {this.state.greater12Hours}
  </Text>

  </View>


  <View style={styles.containerRow}>

   <Text style={styles.welcome}>
    {this.state.less8hours}
  </Text>

  </View>
  </View>
)
}
}
```

This is api.js

```
var api={
    getAttendanceDetails(){
        var url='http://www.myurl.com';
        return fetch(url).then((res)=>res.json());
    }
};
module.exports = api;
```

Comment: `resarray1` is not defined in your `api.getAttendanceDetails().then((res)=>{ ... }` function, so `resarray1[0].value` will give rise to the error.

Comment: it is a state in the AttendanceDetails class , should it be defined in api.js?

Comment: You have to write e.g. `this.state.resarray1[0].value` in that case.

Comment: ok i did that , now i get Possibe unhandled rejection (id:0): undefined is not an object(evaluating '_this2.state.resarray1[0].value'))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you don't need resarray on your state:

```
this.state={
    total:'',
    present:'',
    absent:'',
    off:'',
    unmarked:'',
    totalHours:'',
    averageHours:'',
    greater12Hours:'',
    less8hours:''
};
```

Second, `total:resarray1[0].value` is wrong, because resarray1 is not defined on that context:

```
componentWillMount(){
    api.getAttendanceDetails().then((res)=>{
        const resarray1 = res.data.attendance_details;
        const resarray2 = res.data.attendance_summary;
        this.setState({
            total:resarray1[0].value,
            present:resarray1[1].value,
            absent:resarray1[2].value,
            off:resarray1[3].value,
            unmarked:resarray1[4].value,
            totalHours:resarray2[0].value,
            averageHours:resarray2[1].value,
            greater12Hours:resarray2[2].value,
            less8hours:resarray2[3].value

        })
    }); 
}
```

BTW, you can also use async/await in RN:

```
componentWillMount() {
    this.load();
}

async load(){
    const res = await api.getAttendanceDetails();
    const resarray1 = res.data.attendance_details;
    const resarray2 = res.data.attendance_summary;
    this.setState({
        total:resarray1[0].value,
        present:resarray1[1].value,
        absent:resarray1[2].value,
        off:resarray1[3].value,
        unmarked:resarray1[4].value,
        totalHours:resarray2[0].value,
        averageHours:resarray2[1].value,
        greater12Hours:resarray2[2].value,
        less8hours:resarray2[3].value
    });
}
```